# helm values from kubernetes secrets?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I am using this chart : https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-mongodb-exporter

This chart requires `MONGODB_URI` environment variable or `mongodb.uri` populated in `values.yaml` file,
Since this is a connection string I don't want to check-in that into git.
I was thinking of kubernetes secrets and provide the connection string from kubernetes secrets. I have not been able to successfully find a solution for this one.

I also tried creating another helm chart and using this one as a dependency for that chart and provide value for `MONGODB_URI` from `secrets.yaml` but that also didn't work because in `prometheus-mongodb-exporter` chart `MONGODB_URI` is defined as a required value which is then passed into `secrets.yaml` file within that chart, so dependency chart never gets installed because of that.

What would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: After a few years, have you found any better approach to do this? I have the same exact situation.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I have stored my credentials on Vault and then inject those credentials into the chart at deployment time from the build job (Jenkins).

Comment: if you want to be able to check in your secrets into git, I'd recommend you to use [helm secrets](https://github.com/jkroepke/helm-secrets). It provides a wrapper for the helm CLI and enables you to specify an additional secrets file which contains your secrets in an encrypted way. For encryption, secret backends such as `sops` and `vals` are used. The secrets within your secrets.yaml are decrypted on the fly as you run `helm secrets upgrade ...` in whatever k8s manifest template you referenced them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Create custom chart

---

1. Delete the `secret.yaml` from chart's template directory.
2. Create the k8s `secret` on your own, maybe named `cumstom-secret`
3. Edit the `deployment.yaml`: [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-mongodb-exporter/templates/deployment.yaml#L36)

```
       - name: MONGODB_URI
         valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:
             name: custom-secret ## {{ include "prometheus-mongodb-exporter.fullname" . }}##
             key: mongodb-uri
```

---

#### Solution 2: Use original chart

---

1. Set a dummy value for `mongodb.uri` in `value.yaml`.
2. Use `--set` flag to overwrite the dummy value with original while installing the chart. So, your `git` won't have the history.

```
$ helm install prometheus-mongodb-exporter stable/prometheus-mongodb-exporter --set mongodb.uri=******
```

Comment: so I have to copy original chart when creating custom chart? it's not possible to create a custom chart with original chart added as dependency?

Comment: @AsavPatel no, by custom chart I meant, copy the chart some directory, edit it. And then deploy it from there. Just go to the chart directory and use `helm install <name> <chart-name> `. No need use `repo` name like `stable`.

Comment: Side note. Set command will store values in config-map instead of secret.

Comment: No better solution by the end of 2022? seems like awkward solution to me.